# Do I need to use attach function to get a plot from data

Tags: r, graphics, linear-regression

```
data(iris) 
abline(lm(Petal.Width~Petal.Length))
```

won't create a plot with a line. Any suggestions? Tried attach(iris) but no luck

Comment: NO, you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

```
data(iris)
plot(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, iris)
abline(lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, iris))
```

Always avoid attach. It leads to confusion when you repeatedly `detach` and `attach` data to the environment. Both `plot.formula` and `lm.formula` take a `data.frame` (or other appropriate object) as their second argument; that is where you provide `iris`.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation, `?abline`:

> "This function adds one or more straight lines through the current plot."

So, you must first create the scatterplot. As @Nick K pointed out, always avoid attach. A better way to do that is using `$`, which refers to a column in a data frame:

```
data(iris)
plot(iris$Petal.Width ~ iris$Petal.Length)
abline(lm(iris$Petal.Width~iris$Petal.Length))
```

A shortcut to it would be to use in both functions the `data` argument:

```
plot(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = iris)
abline(lm(Petal.Width~Petal.Length, data = iris))
```

The `data` can be suppressed since it is the second argument in these functions by default.